# Tomcat 8 starts multiple times [LifecycleException]

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I am facing the problem, that Tomcat8 creates multiple running instances, so during the start I get an exception that Address is already in use:

```
06-Jan-2016 10:58:39.175 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:568)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:548)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:260)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:87)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        ... 13 more
```

Top output. Every restart, the new instance of Tomcat is created.

```
top | grep java
14427 root      20   0 1055m 354m  11m S     25  9.2   1:46.67 java
19190 root      20   0 1013m 237m  11m S     19  6.2   1:18.29 java
2655 root      20   0  981m 163m  11m S     18  4.3   0:33.42 java
8537 root      20   0  907m 149m  11m S     18  3.9   0:21.88 java
9997 root      20   0 1052m 456m  12m S     18 11.9   2:24.71 java
14844 root      20   0  897m  51m  11m S     18  1.4   0:07.50 java
5853 root      20   0 1069m 521m  12m S     16 13.6   2:50.83 java
23840 root      20   0  921m 188m  11m S      9  4.9   0:54.05 java
28794 root      20   0  920m 168m  11m S      9  4.4   0:49.11 java
```

Server.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="58005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <!--<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <Connector 
        SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" 
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="true" 
        maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="5" 
        port="58443" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" sessionCacheSize="300"
        keystoreFile="keys/service.jks" keystorePass="apache"
        truststoreFile="keys/service.jks" truststorePass="apache" truststoreType="JKS"
        address="localhost" emptySessionPath="true" 
    />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<!--    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" /> -->


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <!--<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">-->
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      <!--</Realm -->

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />


        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
<!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
-->
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I think the problem can be in the server.xml connector, which I took over from previous Tomcat 6.

However, I really have no idea why is the new instance created each time, when Tomcat restarts and will apreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error states, that the AJP connector cannot be started on port 8009, but in your server.xml it is commented out:

```
Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]

<!--    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" /> -->
```

Do you think this is the correct server.xml?